# Deal with dashes and spaces in T-SQL String functions

Tags: sql-server, tsql, escaping, execution

I am searching for the occurrence of a string in a field on a table.  The search statement is done through dynamic sql with my statement template looking like this.

```
SET @sSQL = 'UPDATE #tempProcsAndJobs SET ' + 
  @columnName + ' = 1 WHERE createStatement LIKE ''%' + 
  @columnName + '%''';

EXECUTE (@sSQL);
```

The above sql produces something similar to

```
UPDATE #tempProcsAndJobs SET LoadSummaryTotalSales = 1 
   WHERE createStatement LIKE '%LoadSummaryTotalSales%'
```

This approach is usually effective, until it runs into something like

```
UPDATE #tempProcsAndJobs SET Nightly SXe Data Transfers = 1 
  WHERE createStatement LIKE '%Nightly SXe Data Transfers%'
```

Then it complains about a syntax error.  I've tried using CHARINDEX, and the same problem arises, the server hates spaces and dashes.  I was wondering if anyone knew how to get around this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate your column names with square brackets, otherwise SQL Server will interpret the spaces and dashes as part of the statement instead of the column name.

```
SET @sSQL = 'UPDATE #tempProcsAndJobs SET [' + 
  @columnName + '] = 1 WHERE createStatement LIKE ''%' + 
  @columnName + '%''';

EXECUTE (@sSQL);
```

This will result in the following statements from your example:

```
UPDATE #tempProcsAndJobs SET [LoadSummaryTotalSales] = 1 
   WHERE createStatement LIKE '%LoadSummaryTotalSales%'
```

and

```
UPDATE #tempProcsAndJobs SET [Nightly SXe Data Transfers] = 1 
  WHERE createStatement LIKE '%Nightly SXe Data Transfers%'
```

both of which are valid SQL.

Comment: Thanks,   I always thought that bracket encapsulation was for database objects,  like table names and sprocs .

Comment: You're right, but columns also are considered objects by the parser.  Along with logins, server names, etc.